# Express abscence of edges in OpenCypher

Tags: apache-age, opencypher

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24427279/express-abscence-of-edges-in-cypher) has an answer for how to find nodes which don't have outgoing edges on neo4j and cypher:

```
MATCH ()-[:A]->(n) WHERE NOT (n)-->() RETURN n
```

However, this does not work on Apache AGE:

```sql
select *
from cypher('graph_name', $$
    MATCH ()-[:A]->(n) WHERE NOT (n)-->() RETURN n
$$) as (n agtype)
```

which gives:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ">"
LINE 3:  MATCH ()-[:A]->(n) WHERE NOT (n)-->() RETURN n
                                           ^ 

SQL state: 42601
Character: 69
```

How can I accomplish the same query in Apache AGE?

I'm using the latest version of Apache AGE (1.5.0) at time of posting.

I've tried variations for the `NOT` clause such as

- `(n)-[]->()`
- `(n)-[r]->()`
- `(n)-[*]->()`

but none have worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equivalent query is:

```
select *
from cypher('graph_name', $$
    match ()-[:A]->(n)
    where not exists((n)-[]->())
    return distinct n
$$) as (n agtype)
```

The difference is that this part of the query:

```
WHERE NOT (n)-->()
RETURN n
```

is replaced with:

```
WHERE NOT EXISTS((n)-[]->())
RETURN DISTINCT n
```